# Android Emulator restarts when sending mock location

Tags: android, mocking, location, emulation, restart

I need some help here. I am working on an application that obtains the user's location. I did refer to a number of websites about this so I'm pretty sure I am not missing any step here (from the codes up to sending mock location). So anyway, my problem is that whenever I send a mock location (using Eclipse's DDMS and telnet) the emulator dies then restarts. I also added permissions (to locate user's coarse and fine location) to the manifest file. I also tried it both on Windows and a Mac but same thing happened. :(

Here's the log, just in case:

```
02-01 13:17:11.793: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Displayed bcorp.mtms/.Main: +4m49s987ms
02-01 13:17:11.883: INFO/ARMAssembler(61): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00001004_00000000 [ 65 ipp] (85 ins) at [0x43ae0520:0x43ae0674] in 7219002 ns
02-01 13:17:11.934: INFO/ARMAssembler(61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x43ae0678:0x43ae0840] in 1115000 ns
02-01 13:17:12.173: INFO/ARMAssembler(61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x43ae0848:0x43ae0a00] in 519000 ns
02-01 13:17:13.833: DEBUG/dalvikvm(390): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 88K, 51% free 2636K/5379K, external 939K/1038K, paused 65ms
02-01 13:17:13.934: INFO/System.out(390): EMERGENCY NUMBERS - DISPLAY PHONEBOOK ---->
02-01 13:17:29.013: INFO/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-01 13:17:29.013: INFO/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic:2.3/GRH55/79397:eng/test-keys'
02-01 13:17:29.023: INFO/DEBUG(31): pid: 61, tid: 134  >>> system_server <<<
02-01 13:17:29.033: INFO/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
02-01 13:17:29.033: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r0 00000000  r1 405b8178  r2 4128fab4  r3 459dcc74
02-01 13:17:29.033: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r4 0000012d  r5 00000000  r6 405b8178  r7 4128fab4
02-01 13:17:29.033: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r8 84301321  r9 84302240  10 00100000  fp 00000001
02-01 13:17:29.033: INFO/DEBUG(31):  ip 82f0e7d4  sp 459dcc60  lr 82f0ab37  pc 82f07d0e  cpsr 00000030
02-01 13:17:29.793: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc 00007d0e  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
02-01 13:17:29.793: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 0000ab32  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
02-01 13:17:29.793: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #02  pc 000012ca  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
02-01 13:17:29.793: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #03  pc 000014ae  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
02-01 13:17:29.793: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #04  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #05  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07cec ab04b082 9301cb04 6f646804 b00247a0 
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07cfc bc08bc10 4718b002 b510b40c ab04b082 
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07d0c 6804cb04 34f89301 47a06824 bc10b002 
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07d1c b002bc08 46c04718 b510b40c ab04b082 
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07d2c 9301cb04 34986804 47a06824 bc10b002 
02-01 13:17:29.803: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f0ab14 91099008 f7fb6aa0 900aeb14 1c3a910b 
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f0ab24 6b646b23 930c1c28 1c31940d f7fd9b0f 
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f0ab34 4906f8e7 44791c28 f7ff3150 b011fe1d 
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f0ab44 46c0bdf0 0000454c 000042c8 00000786 
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f0ab54 f7fbb510 bd10ec7c 4802b510 f7fb4478 
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31): stack:
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc20  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc24  40ab5800  
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc28  00000009  
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc2c  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc30  0000ab90  [heap]
02-01 13:17:29.814: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc34  81d48bd3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc38  0000ab90  [heap]
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc3c  459dcc6c  
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc40  00010004  [heap]
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc44  81d3761b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc48  403e0000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc4c  84300daf  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc50  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc54  459dce00  
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc58  df002777  
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc5c  e3a070ad  
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31): #00 459dcc60  00000001  
02-01 13:17:29.824: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc64  8053bf25  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc68  0000012d  
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc6c  82f0ab37  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc70  4128fab4  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc74  00000003  
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31): #01 459dcc78  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc7c  403e0000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc80  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc84  40418000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc88  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc8c  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.834: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc90  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc94  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc98  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcc9c  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcca0  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcca4  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcca8  db15e000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccac  0000012d  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccb0  459dce56  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccb4  00000003  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccb8  0000000a  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccbc  459dcde8  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccc0  00000000  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccc4  459dce6b  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dccc8  00000001  
02-01 13:17:29.844: INFO/DEBUG(31):     459dcccc  843012cd  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
02-01 13:17:43.163: INFO/BootReceiver(61): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
02-01 13:17:43.203: DEBUG/Zygote(33): Process 61 terminated by signal (11)
02-01 13:17:43.203: INFO/Zygote(33): Exit zygote because system server (61) has terminated
02-01 13:17:43.223: INFO/ActivityThread(370): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'backup' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'batteryinfo' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'usagestats' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'sensorservice' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'activity' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'entropy' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'power' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'meminfo' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'telephony.registry' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'appwidget' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'permission' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'package' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'cpuinfo' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'account' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'content' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'hardware' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'vibrator' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'battery' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'alarm' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'window' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'device_policy' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'statusbar' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'clipboard' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'network_management' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'input_method' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'netstat' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'wifi' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'connectivity' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'throttle' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'accessibility' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'mount' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'diskstats' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'notification' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'location' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'wallpaper' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'search' died
02-01 13:17:43.233: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'dropbox' died
02-01 13:17:43.253: INFO/ActivityThread(390): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-01 13:17:43.253: INFO/ActivityThread(124): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-01 13:17:43.263: INFO/ActivityThread(122): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-01 13:17:43.263: INFO/ActivityThread(117): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-01 13:17:43.283: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'audio' died
02-01 13:17:43.283: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'uimode' died
02-01 13:17:43.293: ERROR/installd(35): eof
02-01 13:17:43.293: ERROR/installd(35): failed to read size
02-01 13:17:43.293: INFO/installd(35): closing connection
02-01 13:17:43.293: DEBUG/qemud(38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 11
02-01 13:17:43.313: ERROR/InputQueue-JNI(124): channel '406a9c38 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'isms' died
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'simphonebook' died
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'phone' died
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.audio_policy' died
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.player' died
02-01 13:17:43.403: INFO/ServiceManager(28): service 'media.camera' died
02-01 13:17:43.603: INFO/Netd(403): Netd 1.0 starting
02-01 13:17:44.693: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(404): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
02-01 13:17:44.703: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(404): CheckJNI is ON
02-01 13:17:45.223: INFO/(402): ServiceManager: 0xad50
02-01 13:17:45.223: DEBUG/AudioHardwareInterface(402): setMode(NORMAL)
02-01 13:17:45.243: INFO/CameraService(402): CameraService started (pid=402)
02-01 13:17:45.293: INFO/AudioFlinger(402): AudioFlinger's thread 0xc650 ready to run
02-01 13:17:45.943: INFO/SamplingProfilerIntegration(404): Profiler is disabled.
02-01 13:17:46.033: INFO/Zygote(404): Preloading classes...
02-01 13:17:46.063: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 78% free 232K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 25ms
02-01 13:17:46.153: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 73% free 282K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 17ms
02-01 13:17:46.293: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 22K, 70% free 316K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 17ms
02-01 13:17:46.403: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 66% free 353K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 17ms
02-01 13:17:46.553: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 63% free 382K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 27ms
02-01 13:17:46.943: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 58% free 439K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 17ms
02-01 13:17:47.103: WARN/MediaProfiles(404): could not find media config xml file
02-01 13:17:47.953: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 99K, 47% free 545K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 31ms
02-01 13:17:48.953: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 272K, 28% free 884K/1219K, external 0K/0K, paused 41ms
02-01 13:17:49.093: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 24% free 931K/1219K, external 0K/0K, paused 38ms
02-01 13:17:49.123: DEBUG/RenderScript_jni(404): RenderScript JNI library not found!
02-01 13:17:49.333: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 19% free 998K/1219K, external 0K/0K, paused 39ms
02-01 13:17:49.733: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 5% free 1281K/1347K, external 0K/0K, paused 58ms
02-01 13:17:49.933: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 24K, 3% free 1310K/1347K, external 0K/0K, paused 56ms
02-01 13:17:50.113: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 6% free 1336K/1411K, external 0K/0K, paused 57ms
02-01 13:17:50.643: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 3% free 1376K/1411K, external 0K/0K, paused 47ms
02-01 13:17:50.923: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 5% free 1402K/1475K, external 0K/0K, paused 59ms
02-01 13:17:51.123: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 3% free 1439K/1475K, external 0K/0K, paused 59ms
```

By the way, this occurs whenever I send mock location.

Any help is truly appreciated. :)

Comment: can you eleborate what activity and code you are impl. in that?

Comment: Well, i placed these code lines inside the onCreate() method of my activity: {LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    Toast.makeText(EmergencyNumbers.this, loc.getLongitude() + " - " + loc.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
 }; }

Comment: and this line of code is added after: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Comment: It is a bug in emulator for sdk 2.3. use earlier one

Comment: It's working now. Downloaded SDK Platform Android 2.1.  Thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: Thanks Vikas and Wiz, I had the same problem, when I switched to sdk 2.1 it worked

Comment: @Vikas You should make your comment an answer, so people don't miss it if they don't read comments.

Answer (score 6):

It is a bug in emulator for sdk 2.3. use earlier one like 2.1